# Spawn A Player when player pass y coordnat

Tags: coordinates, bukkit

I'm working on a plugin. I want to spawn a player when a player come a y coordinates(Fall Down). I tried scheluder (some resources says) but i didn't do it
how can do it?

Thanks For Answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event handler for the PlayerMoveEvent, and then check if the Y coordinate is less than your threshold, and if it is, teleport them to spawn with the Entity#teleport(Location) method.

Comment: If your checking when a player falls into the void you could also check when they take void damage.

Comment: Just don't forget to cancel the event!

Comment: How can i use PlayerMoveEvent with coord.?

Comment: getTo().getY() should return a double